# Progress bar doesnt progress unless reloading page (wordpress dev)

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a php script in backend, each for loop increment the progress based on how many loops it has ran so far

```
update_option("import_varejo_processing_state", $pct)//it's from wordpress
```

where $pct is the progress (%) of the script, then I set a "php.js" code to show the progress in frontend:

```
            function import_varejo_progress_bar(){
                var current_progress = <?php echo json_encode(get_option("import_varejo_processing_state")); ?>//aqui oii
                $('.output-ajax-info').html("<div>Processando: " + current_progress + "<div>");
            }
            setInterval(import_varejo_progress_bar, 500);
```

But the progress goes on (in frontend only) only if I reload the page, I know it's bad practice mixing js with php but in this project it works well as I should execute some js code based in wordpress php events/validations etc.

Comment: *"but in this project it works well"* - Indeed, though you may be misunderstanding what you mean by that.  Now is a good time for you to open your browser's development tools and examine the actual JavaScript code.  You'll find that, in that code, nothing ever changes the value of `current_progress`.  It's always exactly the same.  What *should* cause it to change?  Should that logic be client-side instead of server-side?  Or if it has to be server-side, you would need to provide the updated value to the client-side code.  (e.g. AJAX requests or Web Sockets)